# How can I use multi-header based on the current page in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

As title said, how to set one header region different on each pages with Drupal 7.

*For example:*

*On the page n1 : Header n1 (picture set by DP in Theme configuration)*

*On an other page : Header Different (idealy setted in a content type or in a tpl file)*

If you know a module wich allow me to do this feature, thanks !

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no module needed fore that. can't you just set a block to be displayed on one page only and another block on another page, both blocks you should place in header region. 
this way its more consistent and you can more easily replace/adjust it